# Buffon's needles revisited

Tags: pr.probability, geometric-probability

Hi,
I recently came across the famous Buffon's needle problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle), and there is no doubt that the problem as well as its answer are elegant.
However, the problem I have in mind, is slightly modified. The original problem deals with parallel lines separated by fixed distance (say, m). What if there are squares of side m instead of just parallel lines? How will this affect the probability?
I scratched my brain over this, but could not come up with anything. Can some genius crack this for me?

Regards,
Salil

Comment: Laplace is the genius you require - http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Buffon-LaplaceNeedleProblem.html

Comment: The expected number of lines crossed is equal to the expected number of vertical lines crossed plus the expected number of horizontal lines crossed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is solved in *Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability with Solutions*, the 1965 book by Frederick Mosteller (Problem #54). A very good book to have around in any case.

Comment: hmmm... 54th problem in 50 challenging problems ... :-))

Thanks!


Comment: Yes, there are 56 in total. The book's at my office, so I can't tell you more than that right now, but I can look up the detailed answer tomorrow if you need me to.

Comment: no no ... I will get the book in my college library. Thank you very much for that reference!